# How to resolve IE8 Security warning in a developer prospective

Tags: javascript, html

I am facing attached warning message in all HTTPS pages in IE browser. I know it throw this warning when some thing is requested from HTTP serer on HTTPS pages.

I checked everything. All images are pointing HTTPS links. JS files are also pointing to HTTPS links. But I don't know why this warning is still there.

And IE display this warning after loading the page not in between the loading process.

Can you guys point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Thanks to all of you. Tools that you all suggested are very useful and I got what was the wrong with my page. Actually after loading the page it is sending hidden HTTP request to elsewhere. Thanks a lot for useful tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would highly recommend installing firefox and [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843/), and use the NET panel to track your requests. Then you can find the request that is going over HTTP.

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) works for IE8 if you don't want to use firefox and firebug.

I really can't recommend firebug enough, it's completely awesome. Here is a screenshot of the net console in action.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

maybe you're still including libraries from external servers, install a http sniffer in your IE8 and try to look at these recommendations

http://blog.httpwatch.com/2009/04/23/fixing-the-ie-8-warning-do-you-want-to-view-only-the-webpage-content-that-was-delivered-securely/

Answer (score 1):

You say you've checked JS and images; have you checked CSS files as well?

But the most likely cause of this is a 404 error - if one of your images or scripts returns 'file not found', then the 404 error message will be served instead. But the 404 error will not be in HTTPS mode, so you may get the above error.

If you can't see any obvious loading errors on the page, you can check whether you're getting any by looking in a debug tool like Firebug (the loading error should presumably still happen in any browser, even if it's only IE that throws the warning message).

Hope that helps.

Comment: HTTP errors like 404 will not trigger the warning and they do not change the "HTTPS mode"